EC2 not accessible with ALB configured
I have an EC2 that runs a Docker container which serves a static web app. Here's some of my configuration:
DNS.TF
resource "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = var.domain_name
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = "www.${var.domain_name}"
  type    = "A"
 // ttl     = "300"
 // records = [aws_lb.resume-app-application-load-balancer.dns_name]
  depends_on = [aws_lb.resume-app-application-load-balancer]

    alias {
    name                   = aws_lb.resume-app-application-load-balancer.dns_name
    zone_id                = aws_lb.resume-app-application-load-balancer.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }

  
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "root" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = var.domain_name
  type    = "A"
 // ttl     = "300"
 // records = [aws_lb.resume-app-application-load-balancer.dns_name]
  depends_on = [aws_lb.resume-app-application-load-balancer]

    alias {
    name                   = aws_lb.resume-app-application-load-balancer.dns_name
    zone_id                = aws_lb.resume-app-application-load-balancer.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }

}

resource "aws_route53_record" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.resume-app-cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
}


ALB.TF
resource "aws_lb" "resume-app-application-load-balancer" {
  name               = var.resume-app-application-load-balancer-name
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.resume-app-public-subnet.id, aws_subnet.resume-app-public-subnet2.id] # 2 subnets minimum

  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate_validation.resume-app-cert]
}

ALB_LISTENER.TF
# Create a listener on port 443 for HTTPS traffic
resource "aws_lb_listener" "resume-app-application-load-balancer-listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.resume-app-application-load-balancer.arn
  port              = 443
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate.resume-app-cert.arn
  
  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.resume-app-application-load-balancer-target-group.arn
    type             = "forward"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate_validation.resume-app-cert]
}

ALB_TARGET_GROUP.TF
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "resume-app-application-load-balancer-target-group" {
  name     = var.resume-app-application-load-balancer-target-group-name
  port     = 80 # Port on which EC2 instance listens
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.resume-app-vpc.id

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    port                = 80
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    interval            = 30
    timeout             = 10
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

ACM + ACM VALIDATION.TF
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "resume-app-cert" {
  domain_name       = var.domain_name
  validation_method = "DNS"

  tags = {
    Name = "resume-app-ssl-cert"
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "resume-app-cert" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.resume-app-cert.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.example : record.fqdn]
}

SECURITY_GROUP.TF
resource "aws_security_group" "resume-app-security-group" {
  name        = var.security_group_name
  description = "Allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic for inbound and outbound connections to the web app."
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.resume-app-vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = var.cidr_ingress_80
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = var.cidr_ingress_443
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = var.cidr_ingress_22
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = var.cidr_ingress_icmp
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = var.cidr_egress_protocol
    cidr_blocks = var.cidr_egress_ips
  }
}

I am basically hoping to make the ALB be responsible for terminating the SSL connection. If I understand correctly, when a request arrives to my domain, it should actually be directed to the ALB, which will be responsible for handling the connections. The connection from the ALB to EC2 does go to port 80, which I think should be OK. The domain was accessible on port 80 before I implemented the ALB. Now it is not accessible at all.

Which ports do you open in your Dockerfile? Do you see any targets registered at all?

EXPOSE 80 and EXPOSE 443. What do you mean by targets registered?

I mean do you see in the AWS console any instances/IPs registered in the target group that you create with terraform.

I indeed don't see any targets within the target group created by Terraform.

If I manually add the EC2 to the target group, it shows as healthy, so the EC2 + Docker configuration seems OK, although the website still is not accessible. Of course I don't want to add it manually.

I have added a security_groups record to the ALB.tf file. It made some progression, with an error of 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable when trying to access the website via HTTPS. Still no targets being applied though.

Posting this in case anyone struggles with this as well, I have managed to finally register an EC2 instance to the target group, with this:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group_attachment
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "resume-app-attach-target-to-ec2" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.resume-app-application-load-balancer-target-group.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.resume-app-ec2-instance.id
  port             = 80
}

Although I'm still troubleshooting the fact the EC2 is not accessible, it's still an important part of making this work.
EDIT: Attaching the EC2 to the target group allowed HTTPS access. I also added listener redirection from HTTP to HTTPS.
